# Return checkbox value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, radio-button, haml

I have a form for @invoice_address, and in the form I have two radio buttons for the attribute gender, like this:

```
= form_for @invoice_address do |f|
  .table-responsive
    %table.table
      %tbody
        %tr
          %td
            = f.radio_button :gender, :value => "De Heer"
            = f.radio_button :gender, :value => "Mevrouw"
```

What I want to do, is to get the stored value, so either "De Heer" or "Mevrouw". This is how I'm trying to do that:

```
%td= @invoice_address.gender
```

The problem is that this returns:

```
{:value=>"De Heer"}
```

How can I get rid of {:value=>""} and only get the value?

In case you need it, this is in my schema:

```
create_table "invoice_addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "street"
  t.string "zip"
  t.string "city"
  t.string "country"
  t.string "phone"
  t.string "mobile"
  t.string "firstname"
  t.string "lastname"
  t.string "gender"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: You should go over some ruby basics before you ask for help, you can start here https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was a very obvious solution. Because it saved the whole ":value => "De Heer"" part as a string, I removed the :value =>{} and only filled in

```
= f.radio_button :gender, "De heer"
```

It works fine now.

FYI, I did try this when I first made the form, but for some reason that gave me an error, which is why I added the :value => in the first place. I have no idea why it does work now...